# How to turn this if-else statement into one line short form

Tags: java, ternary-operator

I want turn this if else state into one line, how can I do it? Please help

```
if(bet > 0 && this.getPoints() >= bet) {
    this.bet = bet;
    return true;
} else {
    this.bet = 0;
    return false;
}
```

I tried this

```
if(bet > 0 && this.getPoints() >= bet)? 
    this.bet=bet, return true: 
    this.bet=0,r eturn false;
```

Comment: "I want turn this if else state into one line" Why? I'd be interested to know what you think the benefit would be.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your syntax is incorrect. The syntax of the ternary operator is

```
condition ? valueIfTrue : valueIfFalse
```

So you could use this:

```
boolean shouldUpdateBet = bet > 0 && this.getPoints() >= bet;
this.bet = shouldUpdateBet ? bet : 0;
return shouldUpdateBet;
```

But being more concise doesn't mean being more readable. Choose what makes the code the most readable for you.

Answer (score 1):

Line breaks are stripped out by the compiler anyway so you can just remove the line 
breaks from your code to make it a one-liner! ;)

On a more serious note, you can't do it in a single ternary statement. Because the ternary operator only takes a single expression in the clauses. You can't do the assignment to `this.bet` and `return` something in a single clause.

Also, you shouldn't try to use the ternary operator here. The resulting code would be hard to read & debug.

Comment: Yea maybe I will just leave it like this for clarity

Answer (score 0):

You *could* write

```
   return (this.bet = (bet > 0 && getPoints() >= bet ? bet : 0)) != 0;
```

-- but I wouldn't, for clarity reasons.

Breaking this down:

1. The conditional expression determines the size of the bet, 0 or as-specified.
2. The assignment sets `this.bet` accordingly
3. The inequality determines the return value based on what we put into `this.bet`, which at this point we know to be zero for an invalid bet, or non-zero for a valid bet

Answer (score 0):

I would make it at least two lines for readability:

```
this.bet = bet > 0 && getPoints() >= bet ? bet : 0;
return this.bet > 0;
```

but I feel you're braking [command-query separation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Command%E2%80%93query_separation).
Use one method only for the setting part, next add a method to query bet has a value:

```
class ... {

  int bet = 0;
  void setBet(int bet) {
    this.bet = bet > 0 && getPoints() >= bet ? bet : 0;
  }
  boolean validBet() {
    return bet != 0;
  }
  int getPoints () { ... }
  int getBet() { return bet; } 
  ...
}
```

(fixed the error)

Comment: You likely need to throw some parentheses in there: the assignment operator has lower priority than the conditional operator.

Comment: Yea it’s a assignment, the method is a Boolean setbet() to check the betting is valid or not :/

Comment: thanks @another-dave I was focusing on the CQS and made a mistake